# AngularJs: How can i resolve another service promise inside another method in same service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I have two service methods

```
            getObject: function (url, id) {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                $http({method: 'GET', url: url+'/'+id}).
                    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        defer.resolve(data);
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        defer.reject(status);
                    });
                return defer.promise;
            },

            openModal: function (objid, templateUrl) {
                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: templateUrl
                    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                });

                return modalInstance.result
            },
```

Now i want that when call `openModal` function with `id`

then i need to call `self.getObject(id)` then grab the object and then pass it to `ModalInstanceCtrl`

Answer (score 1):

When `openModal` is called, call `getObject`, and pass that promise to the modal controller using `resolve`:

```
openModal: function(objId, templateUrl) {
  var p = getObject(foo, bar);

  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: templateUrl
    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
    resolve: {
      objectPromise: function() {
        return p;
      }
    }
  });

  return modalInstance.result
}
```

See https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal for more documentation on how to use `resolve` to pass data to modal controller.

Comment: I read it but i did not get how can i get object from objectPromise , will the promise will be automatically resolved  and i will have object available in scope or  i need to resolve it.